# OpenSolaris and NTFS

Tags: linux, operating-systems, ntfs, opensolaris, gnu

Is there any way to mount NTFS partitions in OpenSolaris? This is the main issue preventing me from testing it out for more than a day. I need to be able to mount my external. I have vast experience with GNU/Linux and want to try out other Free-Libre Operating Systems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need the ntfs-3g driver just like on GNU/Linux systems. You can grab it [here from sunfreepacks.com](http://www.sunfreepacks.com/listing/?limit=10&offset=20) as `ASntfs-3g-2009.4.4`. Install the 3 packages on the top first though, GNUBase, ASgettext, and ASlibiconv-1.12.

You can then mount them like so:

```
pfexec ntfs-3g /dev/dsk/c5t0d0p1 ~/Desktop/mount
```

Of course, change the disk and partition accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

An update for mid-2012:  OpenIndiana/Illumos (essentially a community fork of OpenSolaris) continues to use the same approach, but I found a few differences in the setup and a very useful tip from 
DAMIAN WOJSŁAW at http://trochejen.blogspot.com/2011/11/openindiana-and-ntfs-3g.html. The following recipe, which includes initial steps for identifying an external USB harddrive with the NTFS partition on it, was effective for me on OpenIndiana desktop 151_a5:

```
## List attached removable storage devices:
$ rmformat -l
## even though counterintuitive, include the partition number "p0" as shown by rmformat
## Verify the pX partition number that contains the NTFS filesystem, typically "p1".
## make sure to exit without making changes, just looking for the partition number.
$ pfexec fdisk /dev/rdsk/c6t0d0p0

## ntfsprogs were installed, but not the actual ntfs-3g kernel modules
$ pkg search ntfs-3g
$ pfexec pkg install /system/file-system/ntfs-3g

## Something not quite complete about the FUSE install out of the box (thanks DAMIAN WOJSŁAW!)
## ( http://trochejen.blogspot.com/2011/11/openindiana-and-ntfs-3g.html )
$ pfexec ln -s /devices/pseudo/fuse\@0\:fuse /dev/fuse

## OK! Now mount it up
$ pfexec ntfs-3g /dev/dsk/c6t0d0p1 /mnt/backup/
## or you can now put add a vfstab entry about so:
/dev/dsk/c6t0d0p1   /dev/rdsk/c6t0d0p1 /mnt/backup  ntfs-3g -       no      -
```

Answer (score 1):

To mount ntfs:

```
# /usr/lib/fs/fuse/mount -o subtype=ntfs-3g /dev/dsk/cXdYpZ /export/ntfs
```

To unmount ntfs:

```
# fusermount -u /export/ntfs
```