# How to see NTFS partition disk record in opensolaris?

Tags: ntfs, opensolaris

i read [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/115366/opensolaris-and-ntfs) and article from link in [answer](https://superuser.com/questions/115366/opensolaris-and-ntfs/115368#115368). After reading and some manipulation (I have 3 disk, 2 listed in /dev/dsk, third not listed) rise question, how to see NTFS partition disk record (file in /dev/dsk) ? 
My task is to mount NTFS partition.
 Hope, you understand me.
 Thanks in advance.

Comment: i tried command ¨format¨ and appears also 2 disks.

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by 3 disks. Are these 3 different physical disks or just three partitions ?
What says "iostat -En" ?

Comment: ¨iostat -En¨ shows all 3 physical disks. it seems that there are two ways (disk busy or not valid NTFS partition). thanks for command name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been trying to do the same a while ago and here is how I managed to mount NTFS partition on Solaris. It worked for me, I really hope this will work for you.

[How to mount NTFS partition in Solaris.](https://blogs.oracle.com/pradhap/entry/mounting_ntfs_partition_in_solaris)

> This project http://mount-ntfs.sourceforge.net/ NTFS Mount (Solaris), UFS Reader (Windows XP) has released utils for NTFS support for Solaris and UFS reader support for Windows vice-versa so that you can access data across .
>
> The idea here is to use NFSv2 server that has the ability to read raw blocks from a block device and interpret the raw data as per the NTFS on-disk format. You can use the existing NFS client in Solaris to mount via the loopback interface.

Comment: That's it??????

Comment: The mount-ntfs solution you suggested seems no to be maintained any more and is quite unreliable. The fuse based ntfs-3g one tried by alex works much better. I'm using it with OpenSolaris.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to install VirtualBox on Solaris. And then install WinXP inside VirtualBox. It is also possible to give the virtualized WinXP direct access to the NTFS disk. Thus, WinXP can read the NTFS disk, and copy the data to Solaris via CIFS/NFS. For details, go to VirtualBox forum and search. I think the functionality is called "rawvmdk" or something?

ntfs-3g and fuse gives something like 3MB/sec in Solaris. Thus, it is unusable for transfering large amounts of data.

The other option is to connect the disk to another PC on the network and then transfer via CIFS/NFS. This is the easiest option.